# CAS Server Single Sign Out using Java Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, web.xml, cas, jasig

I am trying to implement CAS Single Sign Out using Java Servlet and filter mapping in web.xml.
The Filter in web.xml is something like this.

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/out</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And on '/out' url pattern, calling the java servlet which consists of session.invalidate() method and after that redirecting the cas/logout/. But still i am not able to logout properly.

This is my Log:

```
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-10] (HashMapBackedSessionMappingStorage.java:46) - Attempting to remove Session=[]
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-10] (HashMapBackedSessionMappingStorage.java:55) - No mapping for session found.  Ignoring.
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your log suggests that there was no mapping found for your particular session in the CAS application. Possible reason could be that the CAS application server was not used for logging in hence there was no mapping of the browser session and token. The typical flow goes like this. You try to access a protected resource of application A and are redirected to CAS application login page. You enter authentication details and CAS verifies your details and issues you a token which is then redirected to application A where application A again calls CAS server to verify the token and on success the session with application A is considered to be authenticated. On further access of application A, no further authentication is required. While logging out of application A, you make sure you invalidate the session on A ( which you are doing with a servlet) and also then redirect to logout url of CAS server so that it can also logout the session on the CAS server.

Comment: Thanks Sir, for answering my question.I am exactly doing that as you said. I am using session.invalidate() and then redirecting to the logout url of cas url by using response.sendRedirect("CAS Server Logout URL"); Its successfully redirecting to cas logout url. But, when i clicks on the sign-in button, its again able to login.

Comment: I'm doing something similar to @iamrameshkr and getting the same result. Maybe are my expectations that are wrong? I thought that if I add the filter, it would automatically invalidate the session on the CAS server too (like when verifying the token). What's the purpose of the [`casServerUrlPrefix` filter parameter](https://github.com/Jasig/java-cas-client#configuration-1), then?

Comment: @watery, I believe that the `casServerUrlPrefix` filter parameter is not really used by the filter and it is rather a mistake in the documentation (one of relatively many "typos", I'm afraid).

Answer (score 0):

The `SingleSignOutFilter` works independently of the other CAS filters (like of the ticket validation filter). So you need to map it to both URLs when a CAS ticket is passed to your application, as well to URLs when a single log out request is issued by CAS.

So in the simplest case you just need to change this part of your code:

```xml
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/out</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

... to this:

```xml
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

You can also check the latest [documentation for configuring Single Sign Out](https://github.com/apereo/java-cas-client#configuring-single-sign-out) for more details.